# how to pass the dialogue box buttons name as variable in jquery dialogue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Here I want dialogue box button values 'yes','no'  as a variable.I want to pass the variable butt1  to buttons .

```
 var button ='Yes'
 $("#modal_confirm_yes_no").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        minHeight: 200,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
                'Yes': function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(true);
                },
                'No': function(){
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    callback(false);
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: what you mean by pass to button? you want to access/alert the variable when the button is clicked?

Comment: 'Yes','No' buttons value should come from dynamically  from variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var button ='Yes'
 $("#modal_confirm_yes_no").dialog({
    bgiframe: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    minHeight: 200,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: [
        {text: button, click: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(true);
        }},
        {text: 'No', click: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(false);
        }}
    ]
});
```